# Using Subprocess and Communicate to execute commands on Telnet connection

Tags: python, subprocess, telnet

This is my first query on StackExchange. Kindly excuse, if my question is already been raised and answered. If so, kindly point me to the same.

Query: 
I am trying to establish the telnet connection to a board and then would like run a app after that. I would like to capture both STDOUT and STDERR during whole process. Below is the snippet of my code

Code Snippet:

```
import subprocess
import time

#1. Establish the subprocess 
commandlist = ["telnet"] + ["10.11.12.13"]
p = subprocess.Popen(commandlist,
                     stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                      stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
#2. Give the login name. There is no password
p.stdin.write("root\r")
#3. Adding this for sync to avoid any overlap
time.sleep(1)
#4. Invoke the communicate to execute the application from a specied path on 10.11.12.13 system
stdout, stderr = p.communicate('sh /mnt/path/app\r')
```

At step (4), i tried printing the values of stdout and stderr to see whether the application 'app' has run or not. Unfortunately, it has not even executed the 'p.communicate()' line.

If any one has encountered similar problem or know the solution, kindly help me to fix the issue.

Thank you!!

Comment: `it has not even executed the 'p.communicate()' line.`. What's the output?

Comment: @laike9m: Below is the output
    #STDOUT                                       
    Trying 10.11.12.13...                      
    Connected to 10.11.12.135.                  
    
    (none) login: root
    #                 
    STDERR            
    Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/questions/586492/telnet-results-in-connection-closed-by-foreign-host

Comment: @laike9m: I tried manually connecting to the hardware from my linux server, I dont see any such errors/messages. DO you have any further suggestions on this?.. Thanks.. & Morever that Closed By foreign host will come even when I exit from the hardware through the command 'exit'

Answer (score 0):

Terminate your strings with \n instead of \r?

Consider using telnetlib, instead of rolling your own w/ subprocess?

And finally, if you can run an ssh server on this board, you'll be able to use paramiko and ssh channels, which will help avoid some headaches down the road.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and suggestion. I have tried using '\n' also. But the result is same. The system/hardware I am trying doesn't have ssh. I have to use telnet only with the subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pexpect Library to get your task done.

Pexpect can be used for automating interactive applications such as ssh, ftp, passwd, telnet, etc. It can be used to a automate setup scripts for duplicating software package installations on different servers.

https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/